# pip install PIL -E TICKETS-1 - No JPEG/PNG support

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

I'm using Ubuntu and VitualEnv for my Django project.

I have PIL library installed using Synaptic Package Manager and it is working fine. But when I create an VitrualEnv and try to install PIL using pip it installes but I get this strange behaviour:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53)
              [GCC 4.5.2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.
```

I was hoping that I can use requirements.txt for all my dependencies, but may be PIL have to be somehow manually installed ... but how?

Edit: **Thank you John Keyes**, you are right, I run:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

and after another try for PIL install I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53)
              [GCC 4.5.2]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
-    -------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.
```

Edit: You may need to install `libfreetype6-dev libjpeg8-dev`

Edit: Another good option is to use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) instead of [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [thread on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751455) covers this topic.

Answer (score 6):

And just in case, if you are using virtualenv, you don't need to need to create system-wide symlinks, here is the universal workaround that works on any architecture:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/`dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`/libz.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/
ln -s /usr/lib/`dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`/libfreetype.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/
ln -s /usr/lib/`dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH`/libjpeg.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/
```

And you need to execute these line inside virtualenv activated shell session, symlinks will be created inside your virtualenv `lib` directory.

Command `dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH` is being used to detect main system libs directory (`uname -i` is not reliable). And environment variable `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is set by virtualenv `activate` script.

Answer (score 5):

A solution that seems to work for us (as of PIL 1.7.7) is to uninstall PIL first and then Pillow and then pip install pillow --upgrade.  Of course you need to have libjpeg8-dev installed.

Comment: thought this might be useful: http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/problems-with-pil-use-pillow-instead/