# PIL encoder jpeg not available

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pip install PIL -E TICKETS-1 - No JPEG/PNG support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648200/pip-install-pil-e-tickets-1-no-jpeg-png-support)

I'm working on a picture cropper, and I'm having trouble with my form validation. The form is validated when uploading a GIF picture, but any other format I try raises the following exception:

```
Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.
```

**Form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/pic/">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="View uploaded image"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="crop">
</form>
```

**View**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            *do stuff*
        else:
            logger.debug('Form errors == [%s]' % form.errors)
```

I have installed libjpeg-dev(using apt-get) before installing PIL(using easy_install). At first, I thought this might be due to an incorrect installation of either libjpeg-dev or PIL, but would the problem persists for other formats like png? This problem does in fact occur for png images as well. I'm not getting a jpeg decoder problem, so I'm thinking it's not that, but I'm not sure. Also, I'm using the django development server.

---

## **Update**

I decided to try a reinstall of PIL. I deleted my PIL install folder 
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL`
 and my PIL.pth file (in the same dist-packages folder). I ran the setup.py script using `sudo python setup.py install`. I then ran the selftest.py script, and it fails on the first test:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
*** TKINTER support not installed
*** JPEG support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
*****************************************************************
Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

I'm not sure how to get PIL to work with the unsupported modules listed above. I can verify that I have zlib1g-dev, libfreetype6-dev, liblcms1-dev and libjpeg62-dev, and the libraries themselves installed on my system because when I try to install them with apt-get, it says I already have the latest version.

Comment: Could it be you don't have libjpeg installed? Usually PNG _will_ work as well in case that is the issue.

Comment: When I run sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev, the output says libjpeg62-dev is already the newest version. Is there another way to verify that PIL and libjpeg-dev are working together correctly?

Comment: check if you have:  zlib1g-dev, libfreetype6-dev, liblcms1-dev and libjpeg62-dev, + the libraries themselves.

Comment: after forcing a PIL install, try to use PIL from the python interpreter. (or try to use it before) :)

Comment: I've tried opening and verifying the files themselves in the Python interpreter. I don't get any errors when I run verify() on those files (the .png and .jpg images I'm testing). I'll check if I have those libraries, though. Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: I've verified that I have all of the packages listen in your comment, ashwoods. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try downloading PIL from source, then edit setup.py adding this line:

```
add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu")
```

before this line (214):

```
add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib")
```

then

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

It should work now

Comment: I modified `setup.py` differently, but it also worked. I changed `JPEG_ROOT = None` to `JPEG_ROOT = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"` and then run `setup.py` and it worked.

Comment: for bluehost add add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib64")